# How to enable/disable HTML5 required field validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, validation, cross-browser

I have a form where I need to do conditional validation for 3 field. 
These fields are Email, FirstName and LastName. 
So Email field text-box has value, I need not have to validate FirstName & LastName, I mean later 2 can be empty .
If FirstName & LastName field have value, Email can be empty.

I am using HTML5 required attribute.

How to enable disable HTML5 required validator using jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for value and remove `required` attribute.

```js
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
  if ($('input[name=last]').val() != "" && $('input[name=first]').val() != "")
    $('input[name=Email]').removeAttr("required");
  else if ($('input[name=Email]').val() != "") $('input[name=first],input[name=last]').removeAttr("required");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  First:
  <input type="text" name="first" value="" required />
  <br />Last:
  <input type="text" name="last" value="" required />
  <br />Email:
  <input type="text" name="Email" value="" required />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove

```
$("#txt").removeAttr("required");
```

To add

```
$("#txt").attr("required","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**jQuery**

```
 $('#Email').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('required', !$(this).attr('required'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" nam="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required/>
<input type="text" nam="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
<input type="text" nam="Email" placeholder="Email" required/>

<br/>
<button>
Enable/Disable All inputs
</button>
```

It's like `toggling` the `required attribute`.